# What is the difference between Rmpi and Parallel package in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mpi

I made my R code parallel  in two ways:first by "parallel" package and then by "Rmpi" package. I didn't feel any difference between them. I want to know what is difference between them and which one  is more efficient?